# LDAP Maximum number of users

Tags: openldap

i have an LDAP server which manage users for a unique access point from a several application (web and desktop).
Now i need to import more than 200k entry in a OU (organizational unit) and this number grow even.
My question is: there is a recommendation on the maximum number of users that an ldap server can handle?
A OU can accomodate such a high number of users?

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

When we are talking about 200K entries, I think that the performance of your LDAP service will depend on your server and network resources, not on LDAP technology. But I think that there is really no problem with such amount of data.

To provide better performance to your users, you SHOULD have in mind (when you design project and decide which data to put into LDAP) rule 1:10K (1 time write : 10,000 times read), since LDAP is designed to be very fast to read in change for being very slow to write. Also you MAY think about using more than one instance with replications and load balancer in front of them (if you need more details, I can provide them).

Answer (score 2):

OpenLDAP should be able to handle millions of users, provided you set up the indexing correctly.

Answer (score 1):

I have run eDirectory as the underlying data store for LDAP services with 600,000 objects in one OU, with 2 million, and I know a telecom down under with over 8 million.